# Scala: Cats, OptionT[Future, T] and ApplicativeError

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Some time ago I've started using Cats and found `OptionT` very useful to work with `Future[Option[T]]` in most cases. But I faced with one drawback, to use `AplicativeError` I need to define type alias `type FutureOption[T] = OptionT[Future, X]` to matching `F[_]` required by `AplicativeError` and explicitly specify the type of my expression as `FutureOption[T]`.

```
type FutureOption[T] = OptionT[Future, T] // definition to match F[_] kind

val x = OptionT.liftF(Future.failed(new Exception("error"))) : FutureOption[String] // need to specify type explicitly
x.recover {
  case NonFatal(e) => "fixed"
}
```

If I remove type definition and explicit type specification of my expression the `recover` will not be available because `OptionT[Future, T]` don't match `F[_]`, so it can't be converted implicitly to `AplicativeErrorOps`.

Unfortunately, the example below won't work because there is no `recover` method.

```
val x = OptionT.liftF(Future.failed(new Exception("error")))
x.recover {
  case NonFatal(e) => "fixed"
}
```

Is there any way to avoid such kind of boilerplate code? At least I want to avoid specifying expression types as `FutureOption[T]` explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, I would like to suggest that you make sure you have `-Ypartial-unification` enabled for your build.

This is a fix for [partial unification of type constructors](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5102). You can find a more detailed explanation about the fix [here](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/7a81a395c461fd3a09a6941d4cd040f2).

With partial unification enabled the code you provided in your question compiles fine. Please note that if you're using an IDE (e.g. Intellij) you might get "false negatives" (the code is underlined as incorrect and code completion doesn't work), but the scalac/sbt/gradle will compile it just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was disabled. Now compiles fine without explicit types. Unfortunately, idea highlights the code as incorrect.

Comment: Unfortunately IDEA still doesn't support partial unification correctly. You can go to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11320 and vote to make the issue a higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are at least two ways to cope with the type ascription.

- using type lambdas (this can be intimidating):

  ```
  val a: { type λ[A] = OptionT[Future, A] }#λ
  ```
- using a compiler plugin like [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector), example usage:

  ```
  val a: Lambda[A => OptionT[Future, A]]
  ```

But if you wanted to call `Future`'s `recover`, you can always do:

```
val x = OptionT.liftF(Future.failed(new Exception("error")))
x.value.recover ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I read about the kind-projector, but it's still not quite clear for me how to use it in this case. Could you please provide some more detailed example. 

As about `x.value.recover ...`, I know this option, but I prefer to stay in `OptionT` monad because I have other calculations in it.

Comment: As the [kind-projector documentation](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) states, you can use the type annotations `OptionT[Future, ?]` and `λ[A => OptionT[Future, A]]` if you enable kind-projector inside your build.